# Format multiple dataframe columns with the thousand separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, separator

I was able to put the thousand separator to one column slice. How would I do that to multiple columns?

This works:

```
summary.iloc[:,6]=summary.iloc[:,6].map('{:,}'.format)
```

But this does not:

```
summary.iloc[:,6]=summary.iloc[:,6:].map('{:,}'.format)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `df.applymap`:

```
summary.iloc[:, 6:] = summary.iloc[:,6:].applymap('{:,}'.format)
```

MVCE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1' : np.random.choice(10000, 10), 'Col2' :  np.random.choice(10000, 10)})
df

   Col1  Col2
0  3362  4943
1  7296  1600
2   222  3276
3  8287  8913
4   816  2211
5  8550  9625
6  1020  1453
7  5635  4890
8  4218  3150
9  9601  4744

df.iloc[:, :].applymap('{:,}'.format)

    Col1   Col2
0  3,362  4,943
1  7,296  1,600
2    222  3,276
3  8,287  8,913
4    816  2,211
5  8,550  9,625
6  1,020  1,453
7  5,635  4,890
8  4,218  3,150
9  9,601  4,744
```

Comment: for your example with `df`, how would you write it if only `Col2` had to be formatted with the thousands separator?  Thx.

Comment: The following works `df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].applymap('{:,}'.format)`.  And then output `df`.  Hoping there is a better way.

Comment: @ironv df["col2"] = df["col2"].applymap(...)

Comment: Thanks!  In my use-case only the first column needs to be left out. The rest 15 columns need to be formatted using the thousands separator.  I am looking for an efficient way to set that format.

Comment: @ironv AFAIK the method you outlined above would be the most straightforward way of doing it!